# How to use ForEach loop for enabling the encryption with customer-managed key stored in Managed HSM for multiple storage accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-storage-account

I’m using the following PowerShell script, for to encrypt the Storage Account using Customer-Managed Keys stored in Azure Key Vault Managed HSM.

```
$resourceGroupName='XXXX'
$storageAccountName='XXXX'
$hsmName='XXXX'
$storageEncryptionKey='XXXXX'

#Assign an identity to the storage account
az storage account update `
    --name $storageAccountName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --assign-identity

#Assign a role to the storage account for access to the managed HSM
storage_account_principal = $(az storage account show `
    --name $storageAccountName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --query identity.principalId `
    --output tsv)

az keyvault role assignment create `
    --hsm-name $hsmName `
    --role "Managed HSM Crypto Service Encryption User" `
    --assignee $storage_account_principal `
    --scope /keys/XXXX

#Configure encryption with a key in the managed HSM
hsmurl = $(az keyvault show `
    --hsm-name $hsmName `
    --query properties.hsmUri `
    --output tsv)

az storage account update `
    --name $storageAccountName `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --encryption-key-name 'XXXX' `
    --encryption-key-source Microsoft.Keyvault `
    --encryption-key-vault $hsmurl
```

The above script will work for individual storage account. But I want to enable the encryption with customer-managed key stored in Azure Key Vault Managed HSM for multiple storage accounts in different resource groups using same PowerShell script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need is a loop. (If they are all in the same subscription).

Either you enter your storages in a list yourself or you read them out with az cli.

```
# Setup

$HsmName='XXXX'
$StorageEncryptionKey='XXXXX'
$StorageNames = @('Storage1','Storage2','Storage3')

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# Alternative 1: List Storages by name with az command

$Storages = @()
foreach($StorageName in $StorageNames) {
    $Storages += (az storage account show -n $StorageName) | ConvertFrom-Json 
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# Alternative 2: List Storages with az command 

$Storages =  (az storage account list | ConvertFrom-Json)

# Optional: You may filter the result with 
$Storages = $Storages | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "..." } 

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# Act

foreach($Storage in $Storages) {

    #Assign variables
    $resourceGroupName= $Storage.ResourceGroup
    $storageAccountName= $Storage.Name

    #Assign an identity to the storage account
    az storage account update `
        --name $storageAccountName `
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
        --assign-identity

    #Assign a role to the storage account for access to the managed HSM
    storage_account_principal = $(az storage account show `
        --name $storageAccountName `
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
        --query identity.principalId `
        --output tsv)

    az keyvault role assignment create `
        --hsm-name $hsmName `
        --role "Managed HSM Crypto Service Encryption User" `
        --assignee $storage_account_principal `
        --scope /keys/XXXX

    #Configure encryption with a key in the managed HSM
    hsmurl = $(az keyvault show `
        --hsm-name $hsmName `
        --query properties.hsmUri `
        --output tsv)

    az storage account update `
        --name $storageAccountName `
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
        --encryption-key-name 'XXXX' `
        --encryption-key-source Microsoft.Keyvault `
        --encryption-key-vault $hsmurl

}
```